# Pass a parameter from Main Report to a Subreport

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Apologies for these recent newbie questions, but I'm obviously not asking the search engines the correct questions.

I have a report I'm trying to reconstruct after upgrading from VS2008 to VS2010 introduced errors into an existing Crystal Report. So, I have a semi-working report I'm trying to duplicate.

I have a report containing some subreports. The Main Report has some parameters in queries within "Database Fields" and I need to pass those fields to a particular Subreport's "Parameter Fields" so that it can then reference those parameters in its own queries.

So, my question is: How do I create the association between the query result on the Main Report and the parameter on the Subreport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010** - That's the only one that works currently, isn't it?

When adding a sub-report [or changing the "Change Subreport Links" for an existing report] you can select the parameter on the subreport from the drop-down on the bottom left of the 'Links' tab (or Subreport Links dialog, if editing an existing subreport)

- Once you've selected your field (or Parameter) on the left in the 'Available Fields:' list, click the > button to move it to the right and you'll see link options appear below. **so this is the field from the main report you want to use as a parameter for you subreport**
- Underneath, on the right select the parameter (from you subreport) you wish to link it to.  **This is the parameter in your subreport that you want to use**

does that make sense.

Maybe some images would help.

Comment: I know it's late, but can you add some images? @Frosty

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version, the terminology might be slightly different, but you should be able to right-click on the subreport and select "Change Subreport Links".

From the Available Fields column, find your parameters and click the `>` button to move them over to the "Fields to Link" column.  Click OK when you are done.

Now go to your subreport, and make sure that the parameters you linked are available as parameters; you should be able to use these parameters in your Record Selection for your subreport.